# How can we predict the size of buttons in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'm curious, is there a way that we can predict the size that a button will be (even if just the min size) when laid out by SwiftUI layout code? I'm putting some button in a LazyVGrid, and I know that the buttons are built around an Icon, whose size I am choosing. But when placed in a Button, SwiftUI wants to pad it out (presumably according to HIG), given its context (iOS, in a form or not, etc).

For my first pass, I just told the LazyVGrid that my buttons would be the size of the icon, but of course, that is not correct. I need to give it the size of the buttons including the padding that SwiftUI wants. How can I access this information? I'd rather not go down the route of custom Layout or PreferenceKeys. I'm fairly certain there isn't a way of querying SwiftUI for the answer, but is there some consistent arithmetic that can be applied to the iconSize that will give me an accurate answer? I don't mind that framework updates will obsolete the arithmetic.

Here's some sample code and an image showing what happens when no padding is used:

[image]

```swift
import SwiftUI

let iconSize = 30.0
let iconSymbols = ["house", "applescript", "figure.stand"]

struct ButtonsInLazyVGrid: View {
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: iconSize))]) {
            ForEach(iconSymbols, id: \.self) { symbol in
                Button {
                    // do something
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: symbol)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: iconSize, height: iconSize)
                }
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: If you really feel you need to know, you can get this information from a `GeometryReader` on the button with, yes, a `PreferenceKeys`, but it is not necessary. `PreferenceKeys` are, however, how you query and pass that info in SwiftUI. This is more of a case where you are using the wrong `GridItem`. And you probably don't want to use `LazyVGrid`. If you feel you have to force SwiftUI to put a view in an exact placement, you are using it incorrectly.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "using the wrong GridItem", please? And what would you recommend I do instead of using LazyVGrid? I don't want exact placement, I just want them to not overlap.

Comment: You are using `.adaptive`. `.flexible` won't overlap like you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! The problem is that simply swapping in .flexible makes a single column, which is not what I was going for. I want something that looks like a flow layout, but with columns. The heart of the problem is that to use either of these GridItem Size types, I need to have an accurate minimum value. That gets me back to the original question, how can I know the size of the button that SwiftUI is going to generate?

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason why `LazyVGrid` takes an array of `GridItem`. That is how you determine the number of columns. Run this code and see what happens:

```
struct ButtonsInLazyVGrid: View {
    let iconSize = 30.0
    let iconSymbols = ["house", "applescript", "figure.stand"]
    let columns = [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())]
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
            ForEach(iconSymbols, id: \.self) { symbol in
                Button {
                    // do something
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: symbol)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: iconSize, height: iconSize)
                        .background(.yellow)
                }
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
            }
            .fixedSize()
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to spell this out. I tried the code you've given, and I think what you're suggesting is that I use a GeometryReader to find out the width available to my LazyVGrid, do a division along the lines of `width/(iconSize + padding)` to get a number of columns, and populate the columns array with that many `GridItems`. But the problem now become knowing what `padding` should have been. And that is something that I don't know how to predict.

Comment: To illustrate the problem I still have, add `.frame(width: 200)` just before the last .padding(), and in the preview, look at the AX5 version of the dynamic type variants. For me, it results in the overlapping button borders. This suggests the padding that SwiftUI adds to the buttons needs to be considered.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to build. You have posted a question with what you don't want. What, specifically, are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: For the purposes of this discussion, I would like to know how I can put a series of buttons styled as icons with borders into a LazyVGrid, so that the layout is equivalent to putting them in a bunch of HStacks. I could do that, if only there were an easy way of querying or predicting the padding SwiftUI gives the buttons. The impression I'm getting is that the GeometryReader/PreferenceKeys solution is the main way to go. And it's a bit cumbersome, so I was looking for other ideas. (Custom layouts are probably even more work).

Comment: I thank you for your help here, even if it might look like I'm frustrated. At this point, I feel I'm misusing Stack Overflow to have a conversation. :-) But I'm grateful.

Comment: I would look into using a `Grid` layout. I think that will do what you want with better control.